# React router is not working with webpack server and redux?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-router-dom

I have created below component,

```
const RouterComponent = () => (
 <Provider store={store}>
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/" component={Body} />
    <Route exact path="success" component={SuccessPageComponent} />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

);

export default RouterComponent;

I am rendering this component on my index.js so the default page is loading but if I am using '/success' with url and hit the page, it is not redirecting to the given SuccessPageComponent...
I am using the public path as (const publicPath = path.join('/', '<service_name>', '/');) in my webpack.config file, does that creating a problem?

Answer (score 1):

when you use only path the Body component  it will render in every route you go because Backslash will be in every Route now for the SuccessPageComponent I put Backslash before any route try it maybe

```
 <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Body} />
    <Route path="/success" component={SuccessPageComponent} />
  </Switch>
```

in the start I use it a lot but if you look you need to add Backslash or you go to position of 404 page that you can create by do this:

```
<Route component={NoFound} />
```

like this you can create 404 page
[react-router-doom doc](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start)

Comment: I have tried above solution as well but still it no use. Even this time I am not able to load component on '/' route mapping.

Comment: what you use in Router?